# Show that u = 0 on the surface of V

Tags: partial-differential-equations

[image]

Here is the uniqueness theorem in Evans PDE :

[image]

I can show u is harmonic, however I don't know how to show it = 0  on the surface and the contradiction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

What is the value of $y$ on $\partial U$?

Comment: y > 0 , so y=0 is the boundary , u= xy also equals 0 right ? How about the not contradiction part ?

Comment: @Peter: Correct. The lack of contradiction comes from the fact that $U$ is assumed to be bounded (check the top of the previous page) in Theorem 5. Since $U$ is not bounded in this example, the theorem doesn't apply.